# How to refresh a UIViewController contents when function is called from AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift

I m calling a function from AppDelegate named `updateUI` which is present in another view controller, but after calling that function `tableView.isHidden = true` shows `nil` how do I update the view so as to reflect the changes.

AppDelegate:

```
if (rootViewController?.isKind(of: MovieDetailsViewController.self))!
{
   if notificationContentType == 1
   {
     movieDetailsVC.updateUI()
   }
}
```

View Controller:

```
if currentrentalType == 1
                {
                        defaults.set("true", forKey: "isStillPlaying")
                        self.tableViewOutlet.isHidden = true
                        self.seekBarOutlet.isHidden = false
                        self.seekBarMaximumDurationLabelOutlet.text = self.convertTime(miliseconds: self.milisecondsForUpdateUI)
                        self.seekBarOutlet.maximumValue = Float(self.milisecondsForUpdateUI!)

                        let currentDate = NSDate()
                        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss"
                        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "IST") as TimeZone!
                        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate as Date))
                        let currentDATE = date!.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000

                        let movieStartDate = defaults.value(forKey: "MOVIE_START_DATE") as? Double

                        let difference = currentDATE - movieStartDate!

                        self.seekBarOutlet.setValue(Float(difference), animated: true)
                        let selectedValue = "\(Int(self.seekBarOutlet.value))"
                        let convertedValue = self.convertTime(miliseconds: Int(selectedValue)!)
                        self.seekBarMinimumDurationLabelOutlet.text = convertedValue

                        self.myTimer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateSlider), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                }
```

I also tried with `self.view.setNeedsDisplay()` but then the error is shown in viewController's viewDidLoad() `tableView.delegate = self`

> error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

Comment: Seems like your tableView is always nil. Did you wire it from Interface Builder?

Comment: Share the code how your initiating variable `movieDetailsVC`

Comment: yes I have, the issue is that it shows nil when I call it from appDelegate otherwise it gets executed properly, I need to refresh the contents from that function when the if the condition is true in appDelegate. Thanks

Comment: let movieDetailsVC : MovieDetailsViewController = MovieDetailsViewController()

Comment: Just add this line `[movieDetailsVC view];` after initiating variable 'movieDetailsVC'

Comment: converted your statement into swift and it shows this error Expression resolves to an unused l-value

Comment: for swift `let _ = movieDetailsVC.view`

Comment: after adding this line Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value is shown in viewDidLoad in tableViewOutlet.delegate = self.

Comment: Seems like you controller is used in storboard try to initiate with below code `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YOUR-STORYBOARD", bundle: nil)
let movieDetailsVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VIEWCONTROLLER-IDENTIFIER")
let _ = movieDetailsVC.view`

Comment: the function gets called but the changes do not get reflected in the view and rest all the conditions which are there inside the viewDidLoad also get initialized.

Answer (score 0):

when you call the function from App delegate. The control go directly to the function.
I think tableViewOutlet and some other outlets are not getting properly defined. (maybe getting defined in viewdidload which is not getting called)
The code is insufficient to identify errors.

**Edit:** Instead of calling the function from app delegate. Make a static integer in your UIViewController class and on viewDidLoad check if that integer is set to 1. If yes the set it to 0 and then do the required changes in UI.

```
if (rootViewController?.isKind(of: MovieDetailsViewController.self))!
{
   if notificationContentType == 1
   {
     ViewControllerName.STATICINT = 1
   }
}
```

Inside your VC, in viewdidLoad

```
if ViewControllerName.STATICINT == 1 {
 //required changes
 ViewControllerName.STATICINT = 0
}
```

Comment: it directly goes to the function and yes they get defined in viewDidLoad but I don't want to call that as there are other checks involved.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have created an outlet for tableView from storyboard. The reason here for crashing is, you are trying to access tableview(any) outlet before the view frame is set.

```
if (rootViewController?.isKind(of: MovieDetailsViewController.self))!
{
   if notificationContentType == 1
   {
     print(movieDetailsVC.view.frame)
     movieDetailsVC.updateUI()
   }
}
```

Try to print the Controller view frame, this statement will actually load the view and set its frame, so your outlets should also be instantiated.This is just a work around, i hope it helps.

Comment: it works correctly but the changes don't get reflected i.e the tableView does not get hidden if the condition is true, but runs correctly.